# Details on WSDL Types

Tags: java, wsdl

I am learning WSDL by going through the [online documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) and came across below statement:

> The types element encloses data type definitions that are relevant for
>   the exchanged messages. For maximum interoperability and platform
>   neutrality, WSDL prefers the use of XSD as the canonical type system,
>   and treats it as the intrinsic type system.

I am new to WSDL and finding difficulty in understanding this. what does it mean `WSDL prefers the use of XSD as the canonical type system, and treats it as the intrinsic type system.`?

Also it sys:

> The XSD type system can be used to define the types in a message
>   regardless of whether or not the resulting wire format is actually
>   XML, or whether the resulting XSD schema validates the particular wire
>   format. This is especially interesting if there will be multiple
>   bindings for the same message, or if there is only one binding but
>   that binding type does not already have a type system in widespread
>   use. In these cases, the recommended approach for encoding abstract types using XSD.

What it means `This is especially interesting if there will be multiple bindings for the same message, or if there is only one binding but that binding type does not already have a type system in widespread use.`?

Also what it means about `encoding abstract types using XSD`?