# WSDL abstract vs concrete messages

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am learning about [WSDL from online documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_abstract-v) and came across definitions about abstract message and concrete message:

> Message definitions are always considered to be an abstract definition
> of the message content. A message binding describes how the abstract
> content is mapped into a concrete format.
>
> However, in some cases, the abstract definition may match the concrete representation very closely or exactly for one or more bindings, so those binding(s) will supply
> little or no mapping information.
>
> However, another binding of the same message definition may require extensive mapping information. For this reason, it is not until the binding is inspected that one can
> determine "how abstract" the message really is.

Please help me in understanding what the above definition means? Can you please provide some examples for the same.

When we call a message as `Abstract` and when it will be called as `concrete` in `WSDL` terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message part is considered abstract as it does not really define how the content formatting of the actual SOAP message will look like. Please have a look at [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/) which does a great job on presenting the differences between the available binding styles in WSDL.

Taking the example from this article where the WSDL contract should define a method like `public void myMethod(int x, float y);` you can declare something like that in the WSDL contract:

```
<message name="myMethodRequest">
    <part name="x" type="xsd:int"/>
    <part name="y" type="xsd:float"/>
</message>
<message name="empty"/>

<portType name="PT">
    <operation name="myMethod">
        <input message="myMethodRequest"/>
        <output message="empty"/>
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding .../>
```

Here you just declare the expected elements of a message but you don't really define here how the actual SOAP message matching this definition looks like. This happens in the binding section.

WSDL offers here RPC/encoded ...

```
<soap:envelope>
    <soap:body>
        <myMethod>
            <x xsi:type="xsd:int">5</x>
            <y xsi:type="xsd:float">5.0</y>
        </myMethod>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

... RPC/literal ...

```
<soap:envelope>
    <soap:body>
        <myMethod>
            <x>5</x>
            <y>5.0</y>
        </myMethod>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

... and Document/literal

```
<soap:envelope>
    <soap:body>
        <xElement>5</xElement>
        <yElement>5.0</yElement>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

Document/literal is actually not complete here as you furthermore create own types for `xsd:int` and `xsd:float` and use this types instead of these types as your message type:

```
<types>
    <schema>
        <element name="xElement" type="xsd:int"/>
        <element name="yElement" type="xsd:float"/>
    </schema>
</types>

<message name="myMethodRequest">
    <part name="x" element="xElement"/>
    <part name="y" element="yElement"/>
</message>
<message name="empty"/>

<!-- same port type -->
<portType name="PT">
    ...

<binding ... />
```

Every method has its strength and its weaknesses - please have a look on the IBM article for further information therefore. Due to the limitations and weaknesses `RPC/encoded`, `RPC/literal` and `document/literal bare` are not used that often - instead a modification of document/literal is used - `document/literal wrapped`. Here the advantages of all styles are thrown into one single style - which has its further limits of only allowing one `<part .../>` element for a message:

```
<types>
    <schema>
        <element name="myMethod">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="x" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <element name="y" type="xsd:float"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="myMethodResponse">
            <complexType/>
        </element>
    </schema>
</types>
<message name="myMethodRequest">
    <part name="parameters" element="myMethod"/>
</message>
<message name="empty">
    <part name="parameters" element="myMethodResponse"/>
</message>

<!-- again same port type -->

<binding ... />
```

This results in a SOAP message like this:

```
<soap:envelope>
    <soap:body>
        <myMethod>
            <x>5</x>
            <y>5.0</y>
        </myMethod>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

However, `document/literal wrapped` is not really part of the WSDL:

> In document/literal style of messaging, there exists a pattern which
>   is known as wrapped-document/literal. This is just a pattern, and is
>   not a part of WSDL specification. This pattern has a mention in JSR
>   224 (JAX-WS: Java API for XML based web services). ([Source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-usagewsdl/index.html?ca=dat-))

Hope this also answers somehow your other questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890628/details-on-wsdl-types), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891073/details-on-wsdl-bindings)

Furthermore, the actual transportation may happen on different protocols like HTTP, JMS, SMTP, ..., as already explained by @Namphibian and @JqueryLearner. This happens within the binding section where you define which protocol and binding style (`RPC` or `document`) should be used for which operations:

```
<binding type="glossaryTerms" name="b1">
   <soap:binding style="document"
   transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
   <operation>
     <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/getTerm"/>
     <input><soap:body use="literal"/></input>
     <output><soap:body use="literal"/></output>
  </operation>
</binding>
```

HTH

Comment: Nice answer! Good amount of detail there.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract WSDL contains messages without the transport protocol

Concrete WSDl is abstract WSDl plus transport protocol

Transport protocol may be `JMS` or `HTTP`